# Xcode: move lots of files between targets

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to move files from the Compile Sources build phase of one target, to the Compile Sources build phase of another (same project, no actual moving of files on disk). Xcode (both 5.1.1 and the 6-beta) will not let me drag and drop the files, and manually re-adding them will be tedious.

These files are distributed between different groups, and so selecting them all and changing the Target Membership checkbox would also be tedious.

Is there a fast way to move multiple files between targets?

Comment: I think I had some success just editing .xcodeproj directly. You have to be careful to track which block you're copying where.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy and paste files in Compile Sources from one target to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333507/how-to-copy-and-paste-files-in-compile-sources-from-one-target-to-another)